# Rails STI (Single Table Inheritance) without an abstract class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sti

**Background**

I have a rails 3 app that has a model named `A` with the correspondent table `as`. Now I need a new model `B` that works exactly like `A` but has some other associations and methods (besides those in `A`).

**Problem**

I decided to use STI (Single Table Inheritance). I know I could do something like `A < BaseModel` and `B < BaseModel`, but there's already **a lot** of code assuming a table named `as` and it would require too much work.

So I'm trying to do `B < A`, where `A` is not abstract. I added the `type` column to `as`. Now the model `B` works perfect, but the model `A` doesn't know anything about inheritance and completely ignores the `type` column, so when I do `A.create!` it says that the column `type` cannot be empty. Also `A.all` returns `B` rows too.

**What I've tried**

- Using the default value `A` for the `type` column. *this works but only solves a part of the problem*
- Using a default scope in the `A` model. *the problem with this approach is that it filters out all `B` rows for both models*

**Questions**

- How can I accomplish `B < A` in rails, where none of the models is abstract?
- Are there any other nice alternatives?

Comment: (Haven't tried this.) What about creating a new base model that sets the table name?

Comment: @DaveNewton not sure I follow :\

Comment: Create a class to use as the base class. That class will set its table name using `set_table_name`. A and B will extend this new base class. I don't know if it'll work, it's just what I thought of.

Comment: @DaveNewton sounds nice! I didn't know about `set_table_name`. I'll try that and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveNewton it worked like a charm! Just a detail, `set_table_name` is deprecated. `self.table_name=` is the new thing. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem; glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to create a new base class and have both `A` and `B` extend it.

The base class would set its table name to point to your current `A` table (`as`):

```ruby
class NewBaseClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = `as`
end

class A < NewBaseClass
  # ...
end

class B < NewBaseClass
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class A< ActiveRecord::Base
      self.abstract = false
end
```

**Another approach:**

I would create another model called `C` that would be self contained. It would include    table that would have all of the attributes. And finally models `A` and `B` would have a polymorphic has_one relation to the `C` model.

Comment: Thanks, but `self.abstract` is not recognized by rails. Should I include a gem or something? The alternative approach is kind of what we currently have and it's incredibly confusing for everyone, including the admin users.